# Facebooks ads campaign Nodejs

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I want to create facebook ads by creating facebook ad campaign , but getting error of special_ad_category can't  resolve this

```
const createCompainNew = async () => {
let test5 = 'Create Edge';
let create = await account.createCampaign([special_ad_category], {
    [Campaign.Fields.name]: 'Test Campaign - Delete',
    [Campaign.Fields.status]: Campaign.Status.paused,
    [Campaign.Fields.objective]: Campaign.Objective.page_likes,
})
    .then(campaign => {
        console.log(campaign)
        logPassedTest(test5 + ':Pass', account);
    })
    .catch(errorFunction(test5));
    return create
}
```

Comment: good question, I could not find it in the official doc

Comment: @SultanAli I just found the solution , please try this one

Answer (score 2):

i tried many things but at last tried this and successful to create a ad campaign

```
const createCompainNew = async () => {
let test5 = 'Create Edge';
let special_ad_category = "NONE"
let create = await account.createCampaign([], {
    special_ad_category : special_ad_category,  
    [Campaign.Fields.name]: 'Test Campaign - Delete',
    [Campaign.Fields.status]: Campaign.Status.paused,
    [Campaign.Fields.objective]: Campaign.Objective.page_likes,
})
    .then(campaign => {
        console.log(campaign)
        logPassedTest(test5 + ':Pass', account);
    })
    .catch(errorFunction(test5));
return create
}
```